# Better way to block proxy users with php

Tags: php, proxy, vpn

Actually, i'm using this method to block proxy users.

```
<?php if(@fsockopen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 80, $errstr, $errno, 1))
die("Access not allowed for proxy users."); ?>
```

Have you a better way for that? this method is good, but block VPN users and  think it can block google bots..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a bulletproof way to do this, but this would be pretty much complete:

```
if (get_ip_address() !== get_ip_address(true))
{
echo 'using proxy';
}
```

This  get_ip_address() function was adapted from this answer and goes as follows:

```
function get_ip_address($proxy = false)
{
if ($proxy === true)
{
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',     'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED') as $key)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true)
        {
            foreach (array_map('trim', explode(',', $_SERVER[$key])) as $ip)
            {
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 | FILTER_FLAG_IPV6 | FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false)
                {
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

}

Comment: i just tried your solution, but it doesn't work with hidemyass.com